# Finding the first nonzero value and counting the columns after it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset of daily transactions per customer id, sample below. I'm trying to calculate the lifetime for each customer, the number of days since the customer's first purchase. In the context of the sample data, I want to count the number of days from `2018-04-14` since the last purchase: for id `1052` the length would be 44.

```
trans_date  2018-03-01  2018-03-02  2018-03-03 ... 2018-04-12   2018-04-13  
   id                                                                                   
  1052         30.00       0.0         0.0     ...    14.00          0.0        
  1053          0.0        0.0         10.64   ...    0.0            0.0        
  1054          0.0        8.40        0.0     ...    0.0            9.10       
  1055          0.0        0.0         0.0     ...    0.0            0.0        
  1056          0.0        0.0         0.0     ...    42.21          0.0
```

I know how to find the first non-zero value in the row, but calculating recency using the column_index `trans_date` is where I'm stuck. How do I go about this?

Comment: Do you want to retain the current shape of the data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Convert the column names to dates
dates = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)

def customer_lifetime(row):
    # Indices of the days where the customer has made purchase
    purchases = np.where(row > 0)[0]

    if len(purchases) == 0:
        # The customer never bought anything
        return 0
    else:
        # The index of the first purchase date
        i = purchases[0]

    # The "current" date
    j = len(dates) - 1

    # The customer lifetime is the difference between the
    # current date and first purchase date
    return (dates[j] - dates[i]) / pd.Timedelta(days=1)

df['CustomerLifetime'] = df.apply(customer_lifetime, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
      2018-03-01  2018-03-02  2018-03-03  2018-04-12  2018-04-13  CustomerLifetime
id                                                                                
1052        30.0         0.0        0.00       14.00         0.0              43.0
1053         0.0         0.0       10.64        0.00         0.0              41.0
1054         0.0         8.4        0.00        0.00         9.1              42.0
1055         0.0         0.0        0.00        0.00         0.0               0.0
1056         0.0         0.0        0.00       42.21         0.0               1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html), after checking for non-zero values. We need to add an additional check in cases for all 0s, since `idxmax` would return `df.columns[0]` for that row, which doesn't make sense.  Here I choose to have it return `NaN` using `where`.

```
import pandas as pd
#df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)

my_date = pd.to_datetime('2018-04-14')
u = df.ne(0)

(my_date - u.idxmax(1).where(u.any(1))).dt.days
#id
#1052    44.0
#1053    42.0
#1054    43.0
#1055     NaN
#1056     2.0
#dtype: float64
```